# Simple PHP MySQLi script fails to run

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this same query running on other PHP scripts, but it now won't work. I have troubleshooted for eight hours and frustrated like no one knows.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dave1_guest","password1") 
        or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());

    mysqli_select_db("dave1_main",$con) or die(mysqli_error());

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Inventory limit 100");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
       echo $row['ItemNumber'];            
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried running the query on PhpMyAdmin, and it returns 0 results! This is impossible. When I open the table with PhpMyAdmin, it opens and shows thousands of rows!

When I run the query that PhpMyAdmin uses, it works. But when I add a constraint like `WHERE StockNumber='13922'`, it does not.

Again, the stupid thing is that this script works on other PHP pages on my site.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the functions from `mysqli` to `mysql`, that sounds rather arbitrary. I suggest looking up each function in the manual, checking the inputs and outputs, and doing `var_dump` on the result of each, to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: Like i said. 8 hours debugging. I tried the stuff in that article

Comment: Read my update. I added sentence to last line of my post.

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` inside your loop (and/or `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC`); (BTW, you're fetching one row *before* the loop, is that intentional?)

Comment: The SQL doesn't look like a problem. Maybe you should just start from scratch with your PHP. In fact, learn PHP's PDO instead of mysqli, you'll thank me in the long run.

Comment: Ah, `mysql_error()` won't work with the `mysqli` library - it's probably that.

Comment: You say that PHPmyAdmin shows the data when you open the table, but not when you copy+paste the query? Hmm... does it give a specific error message? My guess would be a possible case sensitivity issue with the table name, or maybe an invisible but invalid white space character ?

Comment: Seems to me like dave1_guest does not have access to this table..?

Comment: So have you tried to add error handling?  If so what errors are you getting?

Comment: Really? You execute that code and NOTHING happens? Describe anything you observe. Enable error messages from PHP, add errors from MySQL. The way this question is asked is basically: It does not work - and nobody can help because the code works on their machines.

Comment: Yes, I have added error handling such as mysql_error() or mysqli_error(). Even things like print_r, or var dumps. Nothing gets outputted. User has rights to DB, I even tried it in PHPmyadmin, logged in as administrator.

Comment: I swear I'm not trying to be a jack about it guys, it really does NOTHING. white screen when I open the page.

Comment: @Zamphatta, interesting. I've not used mysqli since PDO is fine for me. What's up with mysqli, in your experience?

Comment: @Dave, even if you use `var_dump`? Sounds like a fundamental server problem. If you do `echo 'hello';` at the start of the page, do you see that?

Comment: "White PHP Page" is a completely different error than "nothing happens". Enable error output in PHP ini to the browser. Set `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` to on.

Comment: If I echo hello in start of script, and at end of script, both work. Actually, if I echo anywhere it works, except for inside the while loop. It must be a problem with the db returning nothing. the PHP must be good and it does what it is suppose to. It's the Database which has some issue I am certain. Not sure how it came up out of nowhere. I'm guessing I have to contact Bluehost(my host)

Comment: If you say that the query in your code also does return nothing in PhpMyAdmin, but the table is full, then your SQL is to blame. You are sure that you used the correct upper/lower case on all the names? Try to copy the query that PHPMyAdmin uses.

Comment: @Sven So I just did a query that myadmin does, copy pasted from it. It works, but when I add a filter such as WHERE StockNumber='13922' it fails to return anything. So it works without the where, but not with. And I have tired multiple values which I know should be working... must be a server issue? (this is inside PhpMyAdmin, not in PHP script)

Comment: Compare the query you copied from PMA with the one you were originally using. Please update your question with both. There sure is a pattern you are constantly ignoring for some unknown reason, and we haven't gotten to it yet.

Comment: There are at least 3 obvious bugs in this code and you did not edit the question to fix them despite people pointing to them. So they close-vote it or downvote as a hopeless case and move on. You have to take people answers into account or not ask in the first place.

Comment: @DanielVérité Sorry I'm not experienced posting here. Will fix

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the data twice. Remove this line `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: no go. doesn't work either. Even putting the query in phpmyadmin will not work!

Comment: @dave: doesn't remove the fact that you're fetching twice. The fetch BEFORE the while() will simply get overwritten by the fetch inside the loop, trashing the row you fetched. If the query only returns a single row, you'd still "nothing" because you destroyed what WAS returned.

Comment: Then it must be a problem with your DB if it doesn't work through phpmyadmin

Comment: @MarcB you are right, fetch twice my mistake. I removed that, but no avail still. Vector, I'm guesssing this must be the case. All of a sudden this just happens out of nowhere? But it's wierd how my script still work in other places!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your problem, so I do not see the exact error, but I'll try a little help.
First of all:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dave1_guest","password1") or die('Could not connect: ' .      mysql_error());

mysqli_select_db("dave1_main",$con) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Inventory LIMIT 100");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
while($row)
{ 
   echo $row['ItemNumber'];            
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Try this!

Comment: @DaveFes What returned `print_r($row);` ? If empty result - you have an incorrect SQL query.

Comment: Roman, it returns nothing. Like I said above, even running the query in PHPmyadmin returns no rows and no errors.

Comment: @Dave, try to avoid "not working still", "doesn't work" etc, as it doesn't give Roman or Vector (or whoever) anything to respond to. Try to be more descriptive with responses if you can, you'll get better help!

Comment: @DaveFes hen you do not exactly true self SQL-query. If you showed a dump of your database - I would look at what went wrong.

Comment: @halfer i'm not trying to be like that. I'm being as honest and informative as posssible. EVERY thing is super wierd. I have never seen this before. I have no clue what to say to them.

Comment: @DaveFes Then I have nothing to help you.

Comment: So if you had actually run @RomanGorbatko 's code, you would get at least ONE output. If not, then calling mysql_error() will return nothing when actually using MySQLi functions, and the `die()` after `mysqli_select_db()` was triggered.

Comment: `while($row)`? Nice infinite loop there, assuming that the db call didn't return a boolean false due to failure...

Comment: Have you tried with another table? another database? You sure you're running the query against the right schema?